# How to use guice injection to inject a Class in a class with static methods?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, static, guice, inject

I am new to Guice Injection. How do I inject a class into a static variable which I would be using in a static method?

This is the class from which I would like to use my injected variable b in the doLocalize() method.

```
public class A {
   @Inject //Trying to inject this class
   private static B b;

   // Private constructor to prevent initialization.
   private A() {}

   public static String doLocalize(String word) {
       return b.localize(word);
   }
}
```

This is the Module class that I would want to perform a guice injection on.

Note: I cannot change MyModule and B class since its coming from another dependency.

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
   public void configure() {
       bind(B.class);
       // some other binds
   }

}
```

The class I want to be injected in my class A

```
public class B {
    public String localize(String word) {
        //does some stuff
        //returns a modified string
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey. Does my answer answer the question or are you still stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`requestStaticInjection`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#requestStaticInjection-java.lang.Class...-). This is described in the [wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#static-injections).

> Note: I cannot change MyModule and B class since its coming from another dependency.

Then you will need a new module.

```
class A {
    @Inject
    public static B b;
    static void a(){b.b();}
}
class B {
    @Inject public PrintStream out;
    void b() { out.println("Value: b"); }
}

class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    public void configure() {
        bind(B.class);
        bind(PrintStream.class).toInstance(System.out);
    }
}

class AModule extends AbstractModule {
    public void configure() {
        requestStaticInjection(A.class);
    }
}

@Test
public void test() {
    Guice.createInjector(new AModule(), new MyModule()); // Can be in any order
    A.a();
    assertThat(A.b, is(not(nullValue())));
}
```

Comment: heh. so basically same as `A.b=injector.get(B)` during app startup.

Comment: This does all the injection (in this case just one item) and it is where it belongs (in the modules not during the start up).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making the methods on `A` non-static, for a few reasons.

- it's hard to unit test code that calls static methods that reference external services
- using static state makes it harder to make your code thread-safe
- static fields can sometimes lead to memory leaks

I suggest:

```
public class A {
   private final B b;

   @Inject
   private A(B b) {
     this.b = b;
   }

   public String doLocalize(String word) {
       return b.localize(word);
   }
}
```

Note that `b` is final, which is good because you don't want it to be changes and because final fields have certain guarantees in multithreaded environments.

After writing this, I have to wonder why you need the `A` class. Instead, can whatever code calls `A.doLocalize()` instead be injected with a `B` instance?